# React Router 6 and Typescript - why doesn't it pass components through props?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

In react router 6 , in javascript, this works:

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<AppFrame />}>
      <Route path="product" element={<ProductView />} />
    </Route>

    <Route path="*" element={<div>Nothing here</div>} />
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

It displays ProductView inside AppFrame where I've {children}.

---

I'm trying to do the same in Typescript and React Router 6 but it simply doesn't work - it just displays AppFrame. Do I need to do something more that add the {children} tag?

My page layout component:

```
import React from 'react';

type Props = {
    children?: React.ReactNode
  };

  
const AppFrame = ({ children }: Props)  => {
  return (
    <div>
      AppFrame
        {children}
    </div>
  )
};

export default AppFrame;
```

My Presentation Component:

```
import React from 'react';
import AppFrame from '../../Components/Layout/AppFrame';



const ProductView = ()  => {
  return (

    <div>
    Product View
    </div>
  )
};

export default ProductView;
```

My Routes:

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<AppFrame />}>
      <Route path="product" element={<ProductView />} />
    </Route>

    <Route path="*" element={<div>Nothing here</div>} />
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: The first example in Javascript shouldn't, and doesn't, work either. In both JS/TS you'd need to render an `Outlet` for nested `Route` components to be rendered into.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React Router 6 needs to use the new Outlet component, not pass {Children}.

```
import React from 'react';

type Props = {
    children?: React.ReactNode
  };

  
const AppFrame = ({ children }: Props)  => {
  return (
    <div>
      AppFrame
        <Outlet />
    </div>
  )
};

export default AppFrame;
```

Comment: It doesn't work. There aren't <Outlet/> component in react-router.

Answer (score -1):

Because of syntax change. please have look  https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/f59ee5488bc343cf3c957b7e0cc395ef5eb572d2/docs/advanced-guides/migrating-5-to-6.md#relative-routes-and-links

```
// Ah, this is nice and simple!
<Route path=":userId" component={Profile} />

// But wait, how do I pass custom props to the <Profile> element??
// Hmm, maybe we can use a render prop in those situations?
<Route
  path=":userId"
  render={routeProps => (
    <Profile routeProps={routeProps} animate={true} />
  )}
/>
```

Comment: Isn't this v5 code?

Comment: can you share your code in live editor i.e. stackbliz